# Unit test data adapter failed to connect to data source for MSTest when code is run on different machines

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, selenium

I am using Selenium and C# to create our tests, we created our test cases on VS 2010 and then migrated to 2012.

When code is shared across the other person is not able to execute test using Visual Studio 2012. To overcome this issue we changed the .Net framework version to 4.5 and added a testsettings file to the solution, this made the solution work for the location it was currently placed. Again when we changed the location the test stated to fail with following error

> Result Message: The unit test adapter failed to connect to the data source or to read the data. For more information on troubleshooting this error, see "Troubleshooting Data-Driven Unit Tests" (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=62412) in the MSDN Library. Error details: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

I am using TFS data source which is like as follows:

```
 [TestMethod]
 [DataSource("TestMethod1")]
    public void TestMethod1()
    { //Perform Test Actions }
```

and i am constructing the datasource string from App.config file which looks like as follows:

[image]

I am able to run the same test case using command prompt and Microsoft Test Manager but not using Visual Studio.

Please help!